# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass:: - Defining Function in Object

Tags: php

I created a object inline with PHP to work as a model for my SQL table, and when I try to set a function to a object value, I get this error. I simplified the code to show the error:

PHP

```
$test = (object) [
    'autoValue'=>function($name) {
        return $name.' in table.';
    }
];

echo $test->autoValue('Rick');
```

I keep recieving the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> stdClass::autoValue() in

I need to run a function that is stored in **autoValue** in the object, and I cannot set the object with a class.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a group around `$test->autoValue` using `( )`:

```
echo ($test->autoValue)('Rick'); // Rick in table.
```

Full example :

```
$test = (object) [
    'autoValue'=>function($name) {
        return $name.' in table.';
    }
];
echo ($test->autoValue)('Rick'); // Rick in table.
```

Or using a variable

```
$callback = $test->autoValue;
echo $callback('Rick'); // Rick in table.
```